# Redirect to Lead detail page from visual workflow

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visual-workflow

I have a flow which involves a record lookup to Lead object. If the record is found, then user needs to be redirected to the corresponding lead detail page. Lead_id is the flow variable that stores the leadid if found.

My page code is as below:

```
<apex:page controller="MyCallScriptCtrl">
  <flow:interview name="MyCallScript" interview="{!Entry}" finishLocation="{!redirectPage}"/>
```

My Controller code is as below:

```
public with sharing class MyCallScriptCtrl{      
    public Flow.Interview.MyCallScript Entry{get;set;}
    public PageReference getredirectPage(){
       string leadId = '';
       if(Entry != null){
          leadId = Entry.Lead_Id;
       }             
       PageReference send = new PageReference('/' + leadId );
       send.setRedirect(true);
       return send;   
   }
 }
```

But there is compile error that says "Error: Compile Error: Expression of type Flow.Interview.MyCallScript has no member named Lead_Id"

Did i miss anything? Please help me in this regard.

Comment: This issue is solved when the Input/Output type of flow variable is changed to "input and output" instead of default "private".

Comment: Hi Naren! I guess my requirement is somehow like yours. But I am not efficient in Flows so can't understand. I was trying out your logic. Can you please guide me here? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84463/redirect-to-detail-page-not-working